# Is there an efficient way in Polars to reinterpret a single byte in a pl.Binary (or string) as an int?

Tags: python-polars

With pure Python, it is relatively simple to do `ord(A) == 65`, and as a slow Polars method, it is possible to do:

```
pl.Series(["A", "B", "C"]).cast(pl.Binary).map_elements(lambda x: ord(x)) == pl.Series([65,66,67])
pl.Series(["A", "B", "C"]).map_elements(lambda x: ord(x)) == pl.Series([65,66,67])
```

Is there a method (outside of writing a rust implementation, which would be simple, but potentially needless) to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast to list of `pl.UInt8` as:

```py
pl.Series(["A", "B", "C"]).cast(pl.Binary).cast(pl.List(pl.UInt8))
```

Subsequently, you can use the [methods available under the `expr.list` attribute](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/list.html) to work with the list.

Is that good enough for your use-case?

Comment: Thank you! I expected this was simple, I was just missing the cast to a `pl.List`, and trying to deal with the `pl.Binary` directly, which I assumed would be manipulable the same way a pl.List is, but isn't (there's no expr.binary equivalent).

Comment: This is a good one, I didn't know you could do that. If, as the question seems to suggest, they want to assume their string is a single character and just want a single int you can just chain on `.list.first()` at the end.

Comment: The goal here is to efficiently convert a known-valid column of microplate well names ("[A-H]\d+") to row and column indices, so yes, it's easy to just chain that; I don't even need to slice the string, as the rest can just be ignored.  (I realize that letter-65 is probably not the most readable way of doing this conversion, but it's more fun.)